# css @media to test if it is iPhone or Android

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I do a website with the footer always tie to the bottom:

css:

```
 bottom: 0;
```

It was OK until I test it with mobile phone. It appear OK in iPhone but go off screen in Android. So I use `@media` to check the screen size:

```
.footer {
 bottom:0;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.footer {
 bottom:150px;
}
```

Now It works for Android but in iPhone, The `footer` is offset from the bottom. How can I resolve this? Is there a way to detect if there it is iPhone or Android?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: It's because iPhone have large viewport widths, 480px isnt enough. @cgee's comment is interesting, you'll see the proper values of each phones.

Comment: @cgee I tried some of the options there but it still mix up iPhone and Galaxy S3. I think there have same screen resolution. Is there other way? specifically like detecting iOS or some frameworks only in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Tools 
[Google Web Check Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)
**And**

Use firebug addon in firefox. This tool is helpfull